# Creating a new file using JTextField

Tags: java, swing, file-io, actionlistener, jtextfield

Hi I'm having trouble taking the user input and making it receive user input. 
Then taking the user input and using it to create a new text blank text file. 
I can get it to work but when I use JTextField it won't create the file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

## This is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class newGame extends JFrame {
    private JButton reg;
    private JTextField userName;
    private JTextField info;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public newGame() {

        super ("Rock Paper Scissors");

        //creates the text fields
        info = new JTextField ("Welcome to the rock, Please enter your username below");
        info.setEditable(false);
        JTextField userName = new JTextField ("name");

        //impliments actionlistner
        newClass saver = new newClass();
        userName.addActionListener(saver);


        //adds the fields to the Content Layout
        JPanel content = new JPanel();
        content.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        content.add(info, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        content.add(userName, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setContentPane(content);
        setTitle("Rock Paper Scissors The Game");
        pack();


    }


    private class newClass implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event) {

            String newUserName = userName.getText();
            File file = new File(newUserName + ".txt");
            boolean blnCreated = false;
            try {
                blnCreated = file.createNewFile();
            } catch(IOException ioe) {
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog
                (null,String.format("%s",event.getActionCommand()));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're [shadowing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4.1) the variable `userName` so the class member variable of the same name is never set resulting in an `NPE` in the `ActionListener` before the file can be created. Replace

```
JTextField userName = new JTextField("name");
```

with

```
userName = new JTextField("name");
```

Comment: Thank you very much that helped! That local shadowing.